# Powershell txt file filtering

Tags: powershell

I have a log file like this contains lot of lines.

```
connected to TEST01:5555
connected to Android-TEST:5555
up time: 01:39:18, idle time: 06:20:37, sleep time: 00:00:00

connected to TEST02:5555
up time: 01:39:27, idle time: 05:53:12, sleep time: 00:00:00

connected to TEST03:5555
up time: 01:38:27, idle time: 06:24:59, sleep time: 00:00:00

connected to TEST04:5555
up time: 01:39:21, idle time: 06:25:28, sleep time: 00:00:00

connected to TEST05:5555
up time: 18 days, 22:03:19, idle time: 74 days, 04:25:45, sleep time: 00:00:00

connected to TEST06:5555
connected to TEST07:5555
connected to TEST08:5555
up time: 01:49:30, idle time: 07:11:23, sleep time: 00:00:00

connected to TEST09:5555
up time: 18:53:29, idle time: 3 days, 01:51:07, sleep time: 00:00:00
```

I want to output a report by powershell only containing 2 columns, Device name and Up time.

I could not find a way to make a pattern to do select-string or where-object.

Any idea please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work with your data?

```powershell
$filename = '<filename>'

$regex = 
@'
(?ms)connected to (\S+)\s*
up time: ([0-9:]+).+
'@

Get-Content $filename -Delimiter 'sleep time' |
 foreach {
  if ($_ -match $regex)
   {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
     DeviceName=$Matches[1]
     UpTime = $Matches[2]
     }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit about $regex please?

Comment: It's a multi-line single-line regex, in a here string.  Putting it in the here-string lets you embed the newlines, and results in a regex that matches your  data format visually which makes it more intuitive to read.  Basically it matches on two lines, the first one starting with 'connected to ', followed by some non-space characters which are captured in the first capture group ($Matches[1]). The \s* is there in case there might be some trailing spaces. Then the next line does the same with 'up time: ', and captures the string of colons and digits as $Matches[2].

Answer (score 2):

```powershell
$LogFile = Get-Content test.txt
$TempHashTable = @{}
$TheList = @()

For ($i=0;$i -lt $LogFile.Length;$i++) {
    #We will check each line since we don't know when
    #we will get an actual connection, we have to check
    #the line after the current line, if it contains
    #the phrase "up time: " then we know we've got a
    #good connection
    $j=$i+1
    If (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($LogFile[$j])) {
    #Here we just check to make sure the string isn't
    #a completely blank or "Null" value.
        If ($LogFile[$j].Contains("up time: ")) {
            #So we know this line is good, add it to $TheList
            $ComputerName = $LogFile[$i] -Replace "connected to "
            $ComputerName = $ComputerName -Replace ":5555"

            #This is the next line containing the uptime
            $ArrUptime = $LogFile[$j] -split ", idle time: "
            $Uptime = $ArrUptime[0] -Replace "up time: "

            #Add to the hashtable
            $TempHashTable.ComputerName = $ComputerName
            $TempHashTable.Uptime = $Uptime

            #Create the object and add it to $TheList of
            #computers array
            $TheList += New-Object PSObject -property $TempHashTable
        }
    }
}

$TheList
```

Output:

```powershell
ComputerName                                                     Uptime
------------                                                     ------
Android-TEST                                                     01:39:18
TEST02                                                           01:39:27
TEST03                                                           01:38:27
TEST04                                                           01:39:21
TEST05                                                           18 days, 22:03:19
TEST08                                                           01:49:30
TEST09                                                           18:53:29
```

Comment: good script with all explanation i need, but there are situations that $i ne $i+3 and $j ne $i + 1, then the results wont be accurate. I updated log file.

Comment: I updated the script based on your new sample log. I see you accepted the other answer, but hopefully this will help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Another regex example that will allow any other data to be in your file. Requires PowerShell 3.0+ for how I am using `[pscustomobject][ordered]` and the `-Raw` switch of `Get-Content`

```powershell
Get-content "c:\temp\log.txt" -raw | Select-String -pattern '(?smi)connected to\s+(\w+):.*?up time:\s+(.*?), idle time:' -allmatches | %{$_.Matches} | %{
    [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
        Workstation = $_.Groups[1].Value
        Uptime = $_.Groups[2].Value
    }
}
```

**Output from your sample**

```powershell
Workstation Uptime           
----------- ------           
TEST01      01:39:18         
TEST02      01:39:27         
TEST03      01:38:27         
TEST04      01:39:21         
TEST05      18 days, 22:03:19
TEST06      01:49:30         
TEST09      18:53:29
```

**Updated from comments**

Even though you updated the file I only had to make a minor change to get output to account for the "days" portion. Otherwise it was still working. If you are still curious I would guess that maybe you dont have PowerShell 3.0? Either way this does work. Only issue withstanding is which host name you want from the groups. Right now my code pulls the first.

Comment: @RootLoop You also changed the game with the log file. I will update my answer based on the new information.

Comment: This is outputting the wrong results. TEST01 and TEST06 are blank entries.

Comment: @NathanRice it did seem that way but I wanted to be sure. The OP was not explicit in this interpretation that we have.